# Insert HTML in database

Tags: html, reactjs, components, decode

I display text in a React Project from a database (phpMyAdmin). But I want do more.
In my text, I have some lists, and I want React to understand what I want to display.

EXEMPLE:

I want to write this to my database:

```
& lt; strong > blabla & lt; / strong > 
& lt; ul & gt; > & lt; li & gt; > blabla 1 & lt; /li & gt; >
& lt; li & gt; > blabla 2 & lt; /li & gt; >
& lt; li & gt; > blabla 3 & lt; /li & gt; >
& lt; / ul & gt;
```

I want to see this on my website:

**blabla**

- blabla 1
- blabla 2
- blabla 3

I've read on the web that it's a bad idea to insert raw html blasé in SQL.
I wonder how to do it.
I read that some function exist to decode html.
here : https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=2ZrsBajhFoM
but that don't solve my problem.

Thanks for all

Comment: This may solve your question. https://medium.com/@dkode/does-react-escape-html-tags-and-new-line-breaks-in-a-string-that-we-try-to-render-687fbfd083d3

Answer (score 0):

It's called escaping or sanitizing HTML characters. From your question I think you are entering data from PHP

If it's **PHP**, you'll want htmlspecialchars

```
<?php
$new = htmlspecialchars("<a href='test'>Test</a>", ENT_QUOTES);
echo $new; // &lt;a href=&#039;test&#039;&gt;Test&lt;/a&gt;
?>
```

See this link for more information. https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.htmlspecialchars.php

If you are entering data manually you can go to many online sites.
https://www.freeformatter.com/html-escape.html#ad-output
There're escape and un-escape buttons that will transform your HTML in both directions.